# How does m_value get populated when instantiating a double?

Tags: c#

I read the source code of `double` and I found `m_value` field. For the details, see http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs.

My question is:

I did not find ctors or properties that populate `m_value`. How does `m_value` get populated when, for example, I declare `double x= 2.3;`?

Comment: @DavidG: Thanks. But how can `m_value` become `2.3` while there is no properties to change the default value to `2.3`?

Comment: Perhaps it is an intrinsic thing that the compiler does (therefore no setter is required).

Comment: @GrantWinney Yeah, I deleted that just as you commented. Martin found the real reason.